# Problem when running the initial test without freeradius using docker and alpine linux

Tags: docker, alpine-linux, freeradius

I'm trying to test Freeradius with the default configuration, but it's displaying this message when using debug mode:

```sh
$ radtest testing password 127.0.0.1 0 testing123
```

Error message: "Ignoring request to auth address * port 1812 bound to server default from unknown client 172.17.0.1 port 59951 proto udp"

I'm using freeradius on a docker container and released these ports on docker run command:

```
"-p 1812-1813:1812-1813/udp"
```

On dockerfile I added the exposed ports:

```
"EXPOSE 1812 1813"
```

For the docker image I'm using the alpine linux and just make a "apk update" and "apk add freeradius".

The configuration I did was just this one: 
https://wiki.freeradius.org/guide/Getting-Started?fbclid=IwAR23NlAkZXnt9iXggD4M_Ijt57OaPSjjy9pqeJ6Z9yQKGfVvres3vE5cXOk#initial-tests

Comment: You're missing an entry for 172.17.0.1 in ``raddb/clients.conf``

Comment: Thank you, It works.

I added the follow:
` client localhost { ipaddr = 172.17.0.1 secret = testing123 }`
and radtest send me Access-Accept.